# Symfony - Data transformer doesn't do anything?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, tags, transformer-model

I have been working on this for a solid week now and I just don't really know how to do it. So hopefully you can give me some pointers.

The image below shows how I can upload a file and add as many tags as I want to it. The entity MainMedia tags field has a many to many relationship with the Tag entity.[image]

MainMedia entity:

class MainMedia
   {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="fileName", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $fileName;

/**
 * @var Tag[]|ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tags")
 * @ORM\Column(name="tags")
 *
 */
private $tags;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="public", type="boolean")
 */
private $public;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $country;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="publicationNumber", type="decimal", scale=1, nullable=true)
 */
private $publicationNumber;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="leafletCode", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $leafletCode;

/**
 * @var \MyThorluxBundle\Entity\MediaType
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyThorluxBundle\Entity\MediaType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateCreated", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateCreated;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateModified", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateModified;

// ...

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the file")
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "image/png", "jpeg", "image/bmp", "application/msword", "video/mp4", "text/csv"})
 *  maxSize = "1024k",
 *
 */
private $file;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 *
 * @return MainMedia
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}


/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set fileName
 *
 * @param string $fileName
 *
 * @return MainMedia
 */
public function setFileName($fileName)
{
    $this->fileName = $fileName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fileName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFileName()
{
    return $this->fileName;
}

/**
 * Set public
 *
 * @param boolean $public
 *
 * @return MainMedia
 */
public function setPublic($public)
{
    $this->public = $public;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get public
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getPublic()
{
    return $this->public;
}

/**
 * Set country
 *
 * @param string $country
 *
 * @return MainMedia
 */
public function setCountry($country)
{
    $this->country = $country;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get country
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->country;
}

/**
 * Set publicationNumber
 *
 * @param string $publicationNumber
 *
 * @return MainMedia
 */
public function setPublicationNumber($publicationNumber)
{
    $this->publicationNumber = $publicationNumber;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get publicationNumber
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPublicationNumber()
{
    return $this->publicationNumber;
}

/**
 * Set leafletCode
 *
 * @param integer $leafletCode
 *
 * @return MainMedia
 */
public function setLeafletCode($leafletCode)
{
    $this->leafletCode = $leafletCode;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get leafletCode
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getLeafletCode()
{
    return $this->leafletCode;
}

/**
 * Set type
 *
 * @param string $type
 *
 * @return MainMedia
 */
public function setType($type)
{
    $this->type = $type;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get type
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getType()
{
    return $this->type;
}

/**
 * Set dateCreated
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateCreated
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @return MainMedia
 */
public function setCreatedAt()
{

    if(!$this->dateCreated){
        $this->dateCreated = new \DateTime();
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateCreated
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateCreated()
{
    return $this->dateCreated;
}

/**
 * Set dateModified
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateModified
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @return MainMedia
 */
public function setUpdatedAt()
{
    $this->dateModified = new \DateTime();

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateModified
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateModified()
{
    return $this->dateModified;
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->types = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addType(MediaType $mediaType)
{
    $mediaType->setMediaType($this);
    $this->types->add($mediaType);

    return $this;
}

public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

public function setFile($file)
{
    $this->file = $file;

    return $this;
}

public function addTags(Tag $tags)
{
    $this->tags->add($tags);
}

public function removeTag(Tag $tags)
{
    $this->tags->removeElement($tags);
}

public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
}
```

Tag entity:

```
class Tag
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateCreated", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateCreated;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateModified", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateModified;

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */

public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Tag
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

I then have 2 forms, TagType and AddMedia. The AddMedia form tags field uses the TagType form. In the TagType form as shown below I use the datatransformer.

```
class AddMedia extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('file', FileType::class, array('label' => 'File Upload: ', 
'data_class' => null))
        ->add('title')
        ->add('fileName')
        ->add('public')
        ->add('country')
        ->add('type', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'MyThorluxBundle\Entity\MediaType',
            'choice_label' => function (MediaType $mediaType) {
                return $mediaType->getMediaType();
            }))
        ->add('publicationNumber')
        ->add('leafletCode')
        ->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => TagType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'label' => false,
        ))
        ->add('Submit', SubmitType::class);

}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => MainMedia::class,
    ));
}
}


   class TagType extends AbstractType
   {

private $manager;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $this->manager = $manager;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Tag: ',
    ]);

    $builder->get('name')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CollectionToArrayTransformer(), true)
        ->addModelTransformer(new TagArrayToStringTransformer($this->manager), true);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Tag::class,
    ));
}
```

Transformer:

I cant use code tags it is so broken, it just wont post the code indented. [image]

```
    /**
 * Load media database add page
 *
 * @Route("/media-database-add", name="media_add_route")
 * @Template()
 * @return array
 */
public function mediaAddAction(Request $request)
{
    $mediaType = new MediaType();
    $media = new MainMedia();
    $media->addType($mediaType);

    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $mediaForm = $this->createForm(AddMedia::class, $media);

    $mediaForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($mediaForm->isSubmitted() && $mediaForm->isValid()) {

        $file = $media->getFile();
        $fileName = $this->get('file_uploader')->upload($file);

        $media->setFile($fileName);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($media);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash(
            'success-upload',
            'Successfully uploaded ' . $media->getTitle() . ' to the intranet'
        );

        return $this->redirectToRoute('media_add_route');
    }

    return [
        'mediaForm' => $mediaForm->createView()
    ];
}
```

The above controller allows me to upload the files into the database. This is not where i get the error.

The error I get is on the page where I try to edit a file uploaded, so I should be able to edit its tags.

Controller:

```
`    /**
 * edit media database page
 *
 * @Route("/media-database-update/edit/{id}", name="media_update_route")
 * @Template("MyThorluxBundle:Database:mediaUpdate.html.twig")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param MainMedia $media
 * @return array
 */
public function updateAction(MainMedia $media,Request $request)
{
    $editForm = $this->createForm(AddMedia::class, $media);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $media->setUpdatedAt();
        $em->persist($media);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash(
            'media-updated',
            'Successfully updated ' . $media->getTitle()
        );
        return $this->redirectToRoute('media_database_route');
    }

    return ['editForm' => $editForm->createView()];
}`
```

Twig:

```
`    <div class="content-padding">
    <h1>Update Media</h1>

    {% form_theme editForm 'MyThorluxBundle:Forms:fields.html.twig' %}
    {{ form_start(editForm) }}

    {{ form_start(editForm) }}
    {{ form_row(editForm.file) }}
    {{ form_row(editForm.title) }}
    {{ form_row(editForm.fileName) }}
    {{ form_row(editForm.public) }}
    {{ form_row(editForm.country) }}
    {{ form_row(editForm.type) }}
    {{ form_row(editForm.publicationNumber) }}
    {{ form_row(editForm.leafletCode) }}
    {{ form_row(editForm.tags.name) }}

    {{ form_end(editForm) }}

</div>`
```

I know this is a lot of code but I just struggle to explain all this. So the error. I don't really understand why my twig files are still receiving an array when the transformer should be turning it into a string? Thanks!

I forgot to add the error:

```
Expected argument of type "array or (\Traversable and \ArrayAccess)", "string" given
```

Comment: you should call the  `addViewTransformer` method on the formbuilder on the step of tag element, passing as argument an instance of the transformer.

Comment: Sorry could you maybe help me understand what you mean with a code snippet? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like this:

Comment: $builder->get('name')
            ->addViewTransformer(new CollectionToArrayTransformer(), true)
            ->addViewTransformer(new TagArrayToStringTransformer($this->manager), true);

Comment: hi, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

As described in the doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#using-the-transformer), you should attach the transformer to the form's field as example, in your custom FormType:

```
class AddMedia extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
 ....
         $builder->get('tag')
            ->addModelTransformer(new TagAttayToStringTransformer($this->manager));
}
```

Another problem could be that you need to pass an `ObjectManager` instance to the constructor of your transformer, you should find the correct method to do this in the documentation as well

Comment: I added the above to my AddMedia form but the same error occurs. An array is still being returned. :(

Answer (score 0):

Read about this functions:

`prePersist` - The prePersist event occurs for a given entity before the respective EntityManager persist operation for that entity is executed.

`preUpdate` - The preUpdate event occurs before the database update operations to entity data. It is not called for a DQL UPDATE statement.

For example [link](https://github.com/MaximStrutinskiy/GeekHub-WebFish/blob/master/src/MainBundle/Admin/UserAdmin.php#L190)

Comment: I agree that research in general is a good thing but your "suggestion" does not seem to have any relation to the question.  Perhaps a bit of code?

Comment: For example [link](https://github.com/MaximStrutinskiy/GeekHub-WebFish/blob/master/src/MainBundle/Admin/UserAdmin.php#L190)